# Change Server URL in Spingdoc From Remote apis

Tags: spring, swagger, springdoc

I am using the following configuration in my spring boot cloud gateway application:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
#      httpclient:
#        wiretap: true
#        ssl:
#          use-insecure-trust-manager: true
#      httpserver:
#        wiretap: true
      routes:
        - id: humio_log
          uri: ${rewrite.backend.uri:https://xxx.local}
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/log
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/api/log, /api/v1/ingest/humio-unstructured
            - RemoveRequestHeader=Authorization
            - AddRequestHeader=Authorization, Bearer xx
            - ModifyHumioLoggingBody
        - id: openapi_tasks_service
          uri: ${rewrite.backend.uri:http://localhost:8082}
          predicates:
            - Path=/v3/api-docs/tasks-service
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/v3/api-docs/tasks-service, /v3/api-docs
        - id: openapi_sales_org_service
          uri: ${rewrite.backend.uri:http://localhost:8083}
          predicates:
            - Path=/v3/api-docs/sales-org-service
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/v3/api-docs/sales-org-service, /v3/api-docs
        - id: sales_org_service
          uri: ${rewrite.backend.uri:http://localhost:8083}
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/sos/**, /sos/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/api/sos/(?<segment>.*),/sos/$\{segment}
        - id: tasks_service
          uri: ${rewrite.backend.uri:http://localhost:8082}
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/**, /task-and-assignment/**, /task-fulfillment/**, /task-overview/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/api/(?<segment>.*),/$\{segment}
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowedMethods:
              - GET
              - POST
              - DELETE
              - PUT
springdoc:
  webjars:
    prefix: /openapi
  swagger-ui:
    urls:
      - name: tasks-service
        url: /v3/api-docs/tasks-service
      - name: Sales-Org-Service
    url: /v3/api-docs/sales-org-service
```

This results in the following overview:

[image]

Now I want to be able to manipulate the Dropdown of the Servers field. The remote OpenAPI is sending me this localhost:8080 back, but I want to change it to a completely different URL. Do you know of any possiblity?

Answer (score 0):

Add List of ur Servers in spring openApi Configuration like bellow:

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.*;

@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI openAPiConfig() {
        ArrayList<Server> servers = new ArrayList<>();
        servers.add(new Server().url("http://localhost:8080").description("Local Server"));
        servers.add(...);
        
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info().title("My Service").description("My Service Description")
                    .license(new License().url("http://MyDomainLicence.com").name("My info"))
                    .contact(new Contact().name("contactName")
                            .email("myemail@gmail.com")
                            .url("http://contactDomain.com"))
                    .version("1.0.0"))
                .servers(servers);
    }
}
```